# Role-based authentication endpoint problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

@Service

```
 @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email).orElse(null);

        LOGGER.info(user.getEmail());
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email: " + email);
        }

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRoleName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    public Authentication authenticateUser(String email, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(email);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        return authenticationToken;

    }


@Override
    public void saveUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
        User user = new User(userDTO.getUsername(), userDTO.getUserLastname(), userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getPassword());
        user.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRoleName("USER");
        roles.add(role);
        user.setRoles(roles);

        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDTO.getPassword()));
        user.getRoles().forEach(myRole -> LOGGER.info(myRole.getRoleName() + " : here"));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
   @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
               .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/", "/login/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }
```

I create user as a "USER" then only could reach who has "USER" user I mean "GUEST" do not see because those private content for user basicly and I receive HTTP "403" Forbidden error. I could not figure out authentication access. What am I missing

I collected needed parts under service component only asking question, each method has been placed  at own class

solution of this problem

Comment: can you try changing from `role.setRoleName("USER")`  to `role.setRoleName("ROLE_USER")`?

Comment: does not allow because ROLE_ prefix come out defautly in spring boot but I will try again @kcsurapaneni

Comment: You should probably inform a security to authorize resources by role name. If you still didn't or misspelled a role name the authentication filter will always return 403 status code because there's not granted access to the resource. The question should include more details to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I checked  **System.out.println(user.getAuthorities());** returned ROLE_USER @RomanC

Comment: @01d Ok, then let a security to authorize on this role.

Comment: @RomanC I gave authorization all to "USER"s however denied all access

Comment: @01d Yes, but it should be ROLE_USER.